# Confirm changes made by user

Tags: python, django, database

I want all registered users to have the ability to change existing data..
But to make sure they don't mess with it, I want the ability to check the new data before commiting it to my db.
How can I do it as nice as possible, that me and all admins only need one click to reject/accept updated data?

Comment: What did you try? Did you search at all? https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/model-audit/

Answer (score 2):

This job can implement by workflow systems similar [viewflow](http://viewflow.io/) or [GoFlow](https://code.google.com/p/goflow/downloads/list) and others, in this way added/changed data saves on database but waiting to confirm by workflow master actors.